# Can't Remote Desktop to Azure VM from laptop, but can from desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, azure, windows-server

My Windows 10 Pro laptop cannot remote desktop to my Azure windows 2012 R2 VM.

However, my Windows 10 Pro desktop can.

But when I copy the .rdp file from desktop to laptop, then use it, I get:

```
"Your credential did not work."  

<my account>
 [  Password  ]  <-- textbox
 <laptop computer name>\<my account>  
" The logon attempt failed."
```

And, it gets same error if I try to remote desktop with:

```
<VM computer name>\<my account>
```

Comment: what windows build are both win 10 computer on? You can find the build by going to *Settings* → *System* → *About* → OS build: e.g. 17134.286

Comment: Any update in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for unable to RDP is that there was a fix that addressed a CredSSP, “Remote Code Execution” vulnerability (CVE-2018-0886) which could impact RDP connections.  Sometimes, the RDP error message is different. You can refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/unable-to-rdp-to-virtual-machine-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/).

I suggest installing the latest updates both on the windows 2012 R2 VM and laptop.

[Windows 10 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4099479/windows-10-update-history)

[Windows Server 2012 R2 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4009470/windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-update-history)

If that still does not work, you can make sure that if you are typing the correct credentials or rebuild an RDP connection from Virtual machine---Connect ---Download an RDP file on the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion may be this could help you.
https://southjerseytechies.net/blog/remote-desktop-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue on Windows 10 only, they had to break rdp in their latest updates. I can't remote connect to my server running on Windows 8.1 from Windows 10. I get "The logon attempt failed" all time.  But I can connect to it just fine when I switch to Mac and use Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac..

Comment: I actually made it work now when I connected directly to my IP and specified User name as computer name\account